# Protractor : In a particular page, none of the protractor actions are working

Tags: protractor

My protractor script is working fine until a page where reveal.js package is used. I am not sure if that is the reason it causes the scripts to fail, but otherwise the code base is same as the other pages where my scripts works fine.

**Note:** I tried most of the protractor actions (click, highlight, waitForElement, toContain, etc), none of them worked. I could only click the links by inserting jQuery in my script.

CODE:

```
let HighlightElement = function (el) {
          return browser.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", el.getWebElement(), "color: Red; border: 1px solid red;").
            then(function (resp) {
              browser.sleep(2000);
              return el;
            }, function (err) { });
        }
        
let waitUntilElementPresent = function (visibilityOfObject, maxWaitTime) {
          var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
          browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2);
          browser.wait(function () {
            browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3);
            return visibilityOfObject.isDisplayed()
              .then(
                function (isDisplayed) {
                  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(visibilityOfObject), maxWaitTime, "Element taking more time to load");
                  browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3);
                  return isDisplayed;
                },
                function (error) {
                  return false;
                });
          }, 100000);
        }
        
ACTUAL CODE:
            var homepage = new homePageObj();
            utilities.waitUntilElementPresent(homepage.waitScreenText); //here the script is failing. It is just a simple script and it used to work in other pages but it doesn’t work only in some of the pages
            utilities.HighlightElement(homepage.waitScreenText);
            utilities.HighlightElement(homepage.startButton);
            homepage.startButton.click();

Error:
Failed: Wait timed out after 120062ms
```

Using below jQuery I am able to click, but we need to give wait time explicitly for each and every java script that we use, which is time consuming. I am beginner in automation, Kindly help me with a solution.

```
 browser.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('cc-button')[0].click()");
```

Comment: you need to provide the code you're running, the error you get and show what you did trying to resolve it

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov, i have updated the question with code now.

Comment: your code hard to debug as you use a deprecated syntax. But what you described sounds like a problem with browser.waitForAngularEnabled(). Look it up and make sure your page is angular ready

Comment: After giving browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false), it started working, Thank you for the help! @SergeyPleshakov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code started running after proving "browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)" at the start of the script.